# how to access docker service in localhost

Tags: docker, service

I creates a simple service with docker image. how I want to access it in localhost of my system.

```
docker service create --name my-app --replicas 3 -p 9090:8000 my-app-image



docker service ls

ID             NAME      MODE         REPLICAS   IMAGE                 PORTS
ojvi1m6f8b41   my-app    replicated   3/3        my-app-image:latest   *:9090->8000/tcp



docker ps

CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                 COMMAND                CREATED          STATUS          PORTS      NAMES
92b7d0ee0732   my-app-image:latest   "java -jar /app.jar"   39 seconds ago   Up 33 seconds   9090/tcp   my-app.2.corp0f0uln0ng4h9lrk6h09nl
4478d716939a   my-app-image:latest   "java -jar /app.jar"   39 seconds ago   Up 33 seconds   9090/tcp   my-app.1.v3wwxp1xz93sfonimg1uszaqz
52aab839c268   my-app-image:latest   "java -jar /app.jar"   39 seconds ago   Up 34 seconds   9090/tcp   my-app.3.ihpy62i331h48b1mtuhr87z46
```

it seems service is running but I can not access it in http://localhost:8000

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could access it in http://localhost:9090.
8000 is the port inside your docker container not accessible from outside.
The local port is 9090

Answer (score 0):

You're mapping the port 9090 of the host, in this case your local computer, to the container port of 8000. In other words: You should be able to reach it locally on port 9090

[For more information on container networking](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/)